# How to Get() values from a list of entry widgets using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using a button to add a new entry widget every time it is pressed, which works. However, whenever I itierate over the list to get the values in the entry widgets, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What am I missing? I found similar questions but the answers arent' working for me.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run this code
2. Click "Add system block" to add Entry widgets
3. Type something into entry blocks
4. Click "Get Entry Values"
   Expected Results: Whatever was typed in entry blocks are printed to console

   ```
   from tkinter import *
   import tkinter as tk
   from matplotlib.figure import Figure
   from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import(FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
   import numpy as np

   class MyApp:
       def __init__(self, parent):
           self.myParent = parent ###remember my parent, the root
           parent.geometry("500x300+0+0") #Default window size

           global system_block_list, num_of_block
           system_block_list = []
           num_of_block = 0

           self.frm_detail=tk.Frame(
               master=root,
               relief=tk.RAISED,
               borderwidth=1,
               height=100,
               bg="#e0e0e0"
           )

           self.frm_detail.rowconfigure([0,1], weight=0)
           self.frm_detail.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=50)
           self.frm_detail.columnconfigure(1, weight=10, minsize=50)
           self.frm_detail.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")

           lbl_detail = tk.Label(master=self.frm_detail, text="System Diagram", bg="white", fg="black")
           lbl_detail.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="new")

           """""Diagram Buttons Frame"""""
           self.frm_diagram_btns=tk.Frame(
               master=self.frm_detail,
               relief=tk.RAISED,
               borderwidth=1,
               height=300,
               bg="#e0e0e0"
           )
           self.frm_diagram_btns.grid(row=1,column=0, rowspan=1, sticky="nsew")

           self.btn_add_block = tk.Button(
               text="Add System Block",
               width=20,
               height=1,
               bg="#c4fffe",
               fg="black",
               master=self.frm_diagram_btns,
               relief=RAISED
           )
           self.btn_add_block.pack()
           self.btn_add_block.pack_propagate(0)
           self.btn_add_block.bind("<Button-1>", self.handle_add_block)

           self.btn_get_values = tk.Button(
               text="Get Entry Values",
               width=20,
               height=1,
               bg="#c4fffe",
               fg="black",
               master=self.frm_diagram_btns,
               relief=RAISED
           )
           self.btn_get_values.pack()
           self.btn_get_values.pack_propagate(0)
           self.btn_get_values.bind("<Button-1>", self.handle_button1)

           """""Block Diagram Frame"""""
           self.frm_block_diagram=tk.Frame(
               master=self.frm_detail,
               relief=tk.RAISED,
               borderwidth=1,
               height=300,
               bg="#e0e0e0"
           )
           self.frm_block_diagram.grid(row=1,column=1, rowspan=1, sticky="nsew")

           '''TEST STARTS HERE'''

       def handle_button1(self, event):
           #Get value in filename entry
           global system_block_list

           values = [int(entry.get()) for entry in system_block_list]
           print(values)
           return values


       def handle_add_block(self, event) :
           global system_block_list, num_of_block
           '''Generate a new Entry Widget and use grid to place it in frm_block_diagram'''

           system_block_list.append([tk.Entry(self.frm_block_diagram, relief="raised",width=10,bg="white",fg="black")])
           system_block_list[-1][0].grid(row=0, column=num_of_block, sticky='nsew', ipadx=5, ipady=10, padx=10, pady=10)
           system_block_list[-1][0].grid_propagate(0)

           '''reconfigure frm_block_diagram for another column'''
           self.frm_block_diagram.columnconfigure(num_of_block, weight=1)

           num_of_block += 1
           return num_of_block

   #Run the event loop
   root = tk.Tk()
   myapp = MyApp(root)
   root.mainloop()
   ```

Comment: `system_block_list` isn't a list of Entries, it's a list of one-element lists, each containing an Entry.  There was no point in doing it that way, just append the Entries themselves to the list.

Comment: @jasonharper Oh I didn't realize that. Can you give an example of how that would work?

Comment: Just remove the square brackets around the parameter to your `.append()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by jasonharper. system_block_list is not a list of entries, but a list of lists of entries. Therefore changing:

```
system_block_list.append([tk.Entry(self.frm_block_diagram, relief="raised",width=10,bg="white",fg="black")])
system_block_list[-1][0].grid(row=0, column=num_of_block, sticky='nsew', ipadx=5, ipady=10, padx=10, pady=10)
system_block_list[-1][0].grid_propagate(0)
```

to

```
entry = tk.Entry(self.frm_block_diagram, relief="raised",width=20,bg="white",fg="black")
system_block_list.append(entry)
system_block_list[-1].grid(row=0, column=num_of_block, sticky='nsew', ipadx=5, ipady=10, padx=10, pady=10)
system_block_list[-1].grid_propagate(0)
```

All better!